# "Error in optim" usando Hurdle Model

Tags: r

Eu possuo um conjunto de dados, onde a variável resposta do meu estudo possui muitos zeros; por isso, decidi entender a influência das variáveis preditoras usando um "hurdle model". Vejam só como tá meu código:

```
fórmula <- dados$Nº_de_artigos ~ dados$Status_Red_List + dados$Z_Capacidade_Científica +
 dados$Z_Fossorial + dados$Z_Terrestre + dados$Z_Aquática + dados$Z_Arbórea +
 dados$Z_Diurna + dados$Z_Noturna + dados$Z_Crepuscular +
 dados$Z_Meses_Úmidos_e_Quentes + dados$Z_Meses_Úmidos_e_Frios +
 dados$Z_Meses_Secos_e_Quentes + dados$Z_Meses_Secos_e_Frios +
 dados$Z_Desenvolvimento_Direto + dados$Z_Desenvolvimento_Larval +
 dados$Z_Vivípara + dados$Z_Tamanho_Corporal_mm +
 dados$Z_Nº_de_Reproduções_por_Ano

#Onde "Status_Red _List" é uma variável categórica.

resultado <- hurdle(formula = fórmula, dist = "negbin", data = dados, na.action = "na.fail")

#Aí aparece:

Error in optim(fn = countDist, gr = countGrad, par = c(start$count, if (dist ==  :    Non-finite value supplied with optim
```

Alguém sabe como solucionar isso? Já procurei em várias páginas da internet, mas não encontrei uma solução adequada :(

Comment: É muito difícil (talvez impossível) te dar uma resposta definitiva sem trabalhar com os mesmos dados que tu está utilizando. Entretanto, é possível levantar algumas hipóteses. 1) Eu contei 18 variáveis preditoras no teu modelo. É preciso ter um modelo tão complexo assim? Seria possível excluir algumas variáveis utilizando bom senso? 2) Qual é o tamanho amostral? Se ele for pequeno, é possível que teu modelo não convirja.

Comment: 3) Se tu está ajustando um modelo hurdle com binomial negativa, imagino que teus dados estejam com superdispersão muito alta. Talvez seja interessante procurar na literatura como calcular o tamanho amostral pra ter um poder de teste razoável no teu caso. Afinal, pode ser que tu até consiga fazer o teu modelo convergir, mas as inferências a serem realizadas não vão ser úteis, pois o poder do teste vai ser irrisório caso o tamanho amostral seja muito pequeno.